# Angular Material Flex Box

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I'm new to flexbox and it seems really complex compared to bootstrap.  I have a splash screen where I am required to vertically and horizontally center a content:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
        <div flex="30">
            <img ng-src="images/logo.png" src="//:0" alt="example.com" title="Example" />
        </div>
        <div flex="45">
            <h2 class="title">example.com</h2>
        </div>
        <div flex="25">
            <h1 class="bang">Bang!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

however it doesn't center till I add a height to it:

```
style="height:500px"
```

Why does it behave this way? Is my code wrong? This doesn't seem like the right way of doing it.

Also with the items in my second `row` with the `layout-wrap` the last `div` with `flex=25` overlaps  the second `div` with `flex=45`.

Basically what I want to do this vertically and horizontally center a div and be able to split that div into as many columns as I like while maintaining a responsive width that adjusts depending on screen size.

Comment: See updated answer. Does it help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can point you in the right direction - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vXqJaM)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-align="center center">
    <div flex="30">
      <img ng-src="images/logo.png" src="//:0" alt="example.com" title="Example" />
    </div>
    <div flex="45">
      <h2 class="title">example.com</h2>
    </div>
    <div flex="25">
      <h1 class="bang">Bang!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```